# Convert a list of objects to an array of one of the object's properties

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have the following class:

```
public class ConfigItemType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double SomeOtherThing { get; set; }
}
```

and then I make a list of the following classes (`List<ConfigItemType> MyList`)

Now I have a method with the following signature:

```
void AggregateValues(string someUnrelatedValue, params string[] listGoesHere)
```

How can I fit `MyList` in to the `listGoesHere` using the value in `ConfigItemType.Name` as the params string array?

I am fairly sure that Linq can do this.... but `MyList` does not have a `select` method on it (which is what I would have used).

Answer (score 321, accepted):

You are looking for

```
MyList.Select(x=>x.Name).ToArray();
```

Since `Select` is an Extension method make sure to add that namespace by adding a

`using System.Linq`

to your file - then it will show up with Intellisense.

Comment: you need to use using System.Data.Linq; then follow BrokenGlass answer

Comment: fantastic solution. I wanted to access the String "id" in my Object-List. Worked perfect                                                                                            `List<String> somestringlist = myobjectlist.Select(x => x.id).ToList();`

Answer (score 22):

> I am fairly sure that Linq can do this.... but MyList does not have a select method on it (which is what I would have used).

Yes, LINQ can do this. It's simply:

```
MyList.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Most likely the issue is that you either don't have a reference to `System.Core`, or you are missing an `using` directive for `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 6):

This should also work:

```
AggregateValues("hello", MyList.ConvertAll(c => c.Name).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 6):

For everyone who is stuck with .NET 2.0, like me, try the following way (applicable to the example in the OP):

```
ConfigItemList.ConvertAll<string>(delegate (ConfigItemType ci) 
{ 
   return ci.Name; 
}).ToArray();
```

where *ConfigItemList* is your list variable.

Comment: Thanks for posting for the .NET 2.0 crowd!