# Is possible with LINQ to extract from an array of objects the value of one property and create a new array?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm pretty new to LINQ and I wonder if it's possible to do the following thins:

I have an array of objects with several properties. I want to create a new array with the values of one of those properties, so if I have this class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public string C {get;set;}
}
```

this is what I want to do:

```
public class ToDo
{
    private TestClass[] _array;

    private string[] _cProperties;

    _cProperties = queryToExtractTheValuesOfCfromTheArray_array;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a list of objects to an array of one of the object's properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765084/convert-a-list-of-objects-to-an-array-of-one-of-the-objects-properties)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

sure:

```
string[] _cProperties = _array.Select(x => x.C).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ey thanks, I knwo I should had started learning LINQ way before but until now I had't the required "environment pressure" :) So thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
_cProperties = _array.Select(t => t.C); //.ToArray()?
```