# converting list of object to array in c# - what does the "x => x.Name" syntax mean?

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda

I was looking for a solution to convert each object's properties on a List to some arrays when finally I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765084/convert-a-list-of-objects-to-an-array-of-one-of-the-objects-properties)

Then I found this code

```
MyList.Select(x=>x.Name).ToArray();
```

which is the solution to my problem. But I still don't understand on what the variable 'x' means. can anyone could explain to me briefly on how this syntax work?

Comment: x means element in MyList...

Comment: The x on the left of the operator is the input variable which corresponds to x in the query expression.

Comment: It is a lambda expression. please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LINQ `.Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)` extension method expects a Func which takes one argument and returns an object/value of another (or even the same) type.

You have several ways to specify which function to execute for each item in your enumerable:

- Lambda expressions: what you posted in your question. `x => x.Name`: `x` is the input parameter, `x.Name` is the result. Could also be written as lambda statement: `x => { return x.Name; }`. Lambda expressions are a very concise way to write short methods which might only be used once. (In addition, they collect their surrounding scope in closures – but this is irrelevant in the context of your question)
- Anonymous delegate: Mostly the same as above. Would be written as `delegate(YourType x) { return x.Name; }`
- Method group: Define a named method somewhere else, and specify its name: `.Select(this.SelectName)`. `SelectName` would be written as:

  ```
  private string SelectName(YourType x) {
    return x.Name;
  }
  ```

LINQ extension methods generally work on instances of `IEnumerable<T>`, so any type (mostly collections) which can be iterated/enumerated. `.Select()` is used to transform one enumerable of type `IEnumerable<TSource>` to another enumerable of type `IEnumerable<TResult>`. Note, that the `selector` function passed as parameter to `.Select()` is only executed, once the enumerable gets enumerated (by means of `foreach`, `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()`, or others).

With LINQ you focus more on a data centric view of your types. You don't care if `.Select()` internally uses foreach, for, or any other way to get to your collection's items. It might even parallelize the operation (`.AsParallel`).

Of course, most LINQ invocations can be rewritten with simple code, for example:

```
var nameList = List<String>(MyList.Count);
foreach(var item in MyList) {
  nameList.Add(item.Name);
}

var array = nameList.ToArray(); // this is still LINQ,
                                // but I didn't want to bother
                                // with re-allocating the array
                                // or with using indexing
```

Comment: Typo in the last code snippet.  In the function body, you meant to say x.Name.  I voted up because you gave all possible ways to pass parameter to select.

Comment: @Khnle-Kevin: thanks, I've updated my question. Wanted all arguments to have the same name and missed to update the method body.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [lambda expression in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that you can use to
>   create delegates or expression tree types. By using lambda
>   expressions, you can write local functions that can be passed as
>   arguments or returned as the value of function calls. Lambda
>   expressions are particularly helpful for writing LINQ query
>   expressions. To create a lambda expression, you specify input
>   parameters (if any) on the left side of the lambda operator =>, and
>   you put the expression or statement block on the other side. For
>   example, the lambda expression x => x * x specifies a parameter that’s
>   named x and returns the value of x squared.