# How to push all generated objects into a single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Using the following code I want to push `filtered[i]` output into a single array instead of multiple arrays.

Any idea how do I do it?

```js
var checkObject;
var filtered = s.Data.results.filter(function(el) {
  return el.result.indexOf(option) > -1
});
for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
  checkObject = filtered[i].path === 3;
  if (checkObject) {
    var object = [],
      hash = Object.create(null),
      notIn = [];
    object.push(filtered[i]);
    console.log(object);
    //
    object.forEach(function(a) {
      a.result.forEach(function(b) {
        hash[b] = true;
      });
    });

    notIn = s.Data.choices.filter(function(a) {
      return !hash[a.choice];
    });
    console.log(notIn);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This link can give you some informations ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765084/convert-a-list-of-objects-to-an-array-of-one-of-the-objects-properties

Comment: can you pls give me the value of s in second line

Comment: `s = this.settings;` here is the call for json file

Comment: create a global variable`object` outside the for loop. And push to this global `object`.

Comment: @JacobGoh can you please edit my code I dont really get you

Comment: I guess what @JacobGoh means is that you need to declare a global array and then push your items into it. (    var myGlobalArray = []; // you need to push your objects into that array )

Comment: @DevMoutarde yup.

Comment: @MarkusHayner you are creating a new array called `object` in every loop of your for loop. so why not just create an array outside of the for loop, and push to the same array everytime ?